# Exasperated/frustrated at someone’s naïveté

Tags: single-word-requests

What word describes the feeling one has, similar to frustration, in the face of naïveté or obliviousness. The feeling might be associated with a sigh or in particularly bad cases a “face-desk” or face-palm.

Interested in descriptive, interesting, or unusual words rather than common words.

Comment: [_Exasperation_](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/exasperating) might fit; although I don't know if that's descriptive, interesting, or unusual enough for your liking.

Comment: Don't mind exasperation, but I'm interested in finding a word I don't know or haven't come across. Appreciate my question might be too localized.

Comment: Well, in that case, maybe you could try [_goat-getting_](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/get-someone-s-goat)? I'm guessing you haven't [come across that one yet](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=exasperating%2Cfrustrating%2Cgoat-getting&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). :^)

Comment: Stupefying disbelief?

Comment: Astonishing is a good word :)

Comment: Exasperation was a good suggestion. Gob-smacked and stupefied might work, but they're a bit stronger.

Comment: How about "flustered" instead of "frustrated"?

Comment: As Gizmoduck would say in DuckTales, 'blathering blatherskite".

Comment: I bet you could find something suitable by browsing tv tropes starting at the entry for "face-palm" and going from there. I'm providing a link, but follow at your own risk! I accidentally went to tv tropes once and didn't come back for like three days. http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FacePalm

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly be nonplussed by a person's behaviour under those circumstances.

**Addendum:** Just to clarify slightly, in line with the comments below, as I hadn't realised this word carries somewhat different meanings, depending on where you are located. The meaning I had in mind was:

**nonplussed**
adjective
(of a person) surprised and confused so much that they are unsure how to react.

Comment: Nonplussed means to be indifferent. Halfway between exasperated and its antonym "delighted". If you re-edit your answer I might feel less vexed. :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA, not on the right-hand side of the [pond](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nonplussed).

Comment: In light of your correction, if @user48193 edits his answer, I will change my vote. As it is I am not allowed by ELU rules.

Comment: +1 now! Sorry, I was unaware of nonplussed double meaning.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm interested in finding a word I don't know or haven't come across.

- [**abawed**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abawed?rdfrom=Abawed)
- [**vexed**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vexed)
- [**gloppened**](http://www.wordnik.com/words/gloppen)
- [**dumbfounded**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dumbfounded)
- [**obmutescent**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/obmutescent)
- [**flabbergasted**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flabbergasted)
- [**discombobulated**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/discombobulated)

Comment: OED has no citations for ‘abawed’ after 1532, perhaps a bit _too_ archaic. ‘Gloppen’ is a verb, the adjective is ‘gloppened’. ‘Obmutescent’ doesn’t really carry the meaning of being exasperated at someone’s naïveté—it just meant ‘persistently silent’. ‘Discombobulated’ is more being disconcerted or uncomfortable than actually exasperated or frustrated.

Comment: Thanks, edited gloppen. I opted for obmutescent because it's similar to dumbfounded, in that a person is speechless in a "face-palm" moment. Only the moment is prolonged. I know it's a stretch, but OP can decide for himself which, if any, he prefers.

Comment: ‘Dumbfounded’ is different, because it’s a passive participle of a transitive verb: it implies _having been made to be_ silent from something that just leaves you speechless. ‘Obmutescent’, on the other hand, is active and doesn’t carry this nuance. Rather, it seems to be used mostly of people or objects that are forced to silence by someone in power, or stubbornly remain stony-faced and silent even when beseeched.

Comment: I've 1+ your comment because I agree but nevertheless it reminded me of the Italian, muto, which can be used as an imperative: "shut up" or to describe when someone is so shocked or so surprised as to be struck dumb. Perhaps it does not fit exactly the OP's requisite but it is fairly rare and quite interesting and that is why I suggested the word.

Comment: Quite happy with archaic words. (It would be quite greedy to ask for unusual words in regular use!) I think obmutescent and abawed are definitely relevant and get an upvote because they're new and unusual, though I think dumbfounded captures the situation better.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I enjoy flummoxed.